# FormatUrl Error publishing in Visual Studio Forms

Tags: c#, .net, publishing

Today for the first time I tried to publish an app I built because it has dependencies it needs to include in the build. But when publishing from the powershell with line `dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true` I get this error:

> error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateTrustInfo" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Any pointers as to what my next step should be? Am I doing anything wrong?

Some more details:

The project is unsigned.

I use WindowsAPICodePack.

Yes, publishing via the interface works fine, but doesn't create a single file. I want to create a single file via either CLI or the interface.

I have added some lines in my .csproj file:

```
<GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>CurrentArchitecture</GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
<GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>CurrentRuntime</GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
<GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources>true</GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
```

Edit: adding `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` to my .csproj file did not work.

Comment: I had a similar problem using `roslyn` so I had to add the reference to the dll in the .csproj in the `<ItemGroup>` tag removing the dependency at runtime. [Here the correction](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/47517#discussioncomment-64145)

Comment: @mijkolsmith Did you resolve this?  I have the same exact issue.

Comment: In the end, I've just given up trying to push it into a self-contained single file executable. I believe it's not possible otherwise because you need the dll to execute the program. I used a dotnet publish command but I don't remember exactly what one, although it was a simple one.